# Box Rest APIv2: Move File or Folder

Tags: box-api

There is a [move operation](http://developers.box.net/w/page/12923941/ApiFunction_move) in v1 API.

But is there any equivalent for v2 Rest API? There is copy function in V2, I tried to replace it as `move` but no love, with operation not permitted error or something like that:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/files/FILE_ID/move \
  -H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN" \
  -d '{"parent": {"id" : FOLDER_ID}}' \
  -X MOVE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by updating the parent of the item via a PUT request i.e.

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/files/FILE_ID \
    -H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN" \
    -d '{"parent": {"id": "THE_NEW_PARENT_ID"}}' \
    -X PUT
```

Comment: It is there under 'Update a File's Informstion', although it's not hugely pronounced http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-update-a-files-information