# Box API Java: How can I move a file into another folder?

Tags: java, box-api, box

So I am trying to move a file into another folder.
The box api says the following

> To move a folder, update the ID of its parent.

But there doesn't seem to be a method on the BoxItem.Info to setID(), like there is setName()

I'm trying to do something similar to the api example [here](https://developer.box.com/reference#update-a-files-information)

```
BoxFile file = new BoxFile(api, fileID);
BoxFile.Info info = file.new Info();
String parentID = info.getParent().getID();

BoxFolder parentFolder = new BoxFolder(api, parentID);
BoxFolder.Info parentInfo = parentFolder.new Info();

parentInfo.setID(newID); // Method doesn't exist

parentFolder.updateInfo(parentInfo);
```

It also seems strange to me that there isn't a file method to simply .move(), it exists for folders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038068/box-rest-apiv2-move-file-or-folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `updateInfo` method, use `move(BoxFolder destination)` on the file to be moved with the destination folder.

Code Sample:

```
String fileID = "1234";
String destinationFolderID = "5678";
BoxFile file = new BoxFile(api, fileID);
BoxFolder destinationFolder = new BoxFolder(destinationFolderID);
file.move(destinationFolder)
```

Also, to avoid name conflicts in the destination folder, you can optionally provide a new name for the file to `move(BoxFolder destination, String newName)`. The file will be placed into the destination folder with the new name.

Code Sample:

```
String fileID = "1234";
String destinationFolderID = "5678";
BoxFile file = new BoxFile(api, fileID);
BoxFolder destinationFolder = new BoxFolder(destinationFolderID);
file.move(destinationFolder, "Vacation Photo (1).jpg");
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted thank you! Wish this was reflected in the API documentation.